# Combusting engine braking: is part throttle more effective than no throttle?

Tags: automotive-engineering, combustion

A counterintuitive question. An engine when in overrun generates a braking torque. This is generally considered to be because the engine is working as an air pump past a closed throttle. However that only makes sense if there continues to be airflow.

It seems plausible that if the throttle were completely shut and any idle valves, recirc valves etc. would be closed, then no air would pump and now the engine can do no work on the flow to cause braking. Intuitively then one would get *less* engine braking with completely closed throttle, than if some air were allowed to pass.

A potential example *in the wild*: a vacuum cleaner that gets choked off actually overspeeds, presumably because there is less air to resist the impeller's rotation.

Is there a non-zero throttle position for maximum engine braking?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jake+brake&ia=web

Comment: A Jake brake is an utterly different concept (compression braking)for use on engines without a throttle. How does this help?

Answer (score 1):

An engine isn't a vacuum cleaner.

First, only spark ignition engines do this without an add-on.  Compression-ignition (Diesel) engines don't have a traditional "throttle," that is, a valve that closes off air intake.  So they need the addition of what is traditionally called (at least in the US) a Jake Brake to redirect flows in an unpowered engine.  This is why semis are so loud when they use engine braking, thus why it is prohibited in some places.

Second, in a spark-ignition (gas/petrol) engine, the throttle is never completely closed, but even if it were, it would still be effective as an engine brake.  The engine is pulling against the vacuum, and vacuum is maximized when the throttle is shut.  Further, any modern ODB II car will add fuel as soon as you touch the throttle, and a traditional carbuerated engine will pull more fuel as well, both working against you.

Comment: "if the throttle were completely shut and any idle valves, recirc valves etc. would be closed" is the premise. And while yes it pulls against the vacuum, the vacuum pulls straight back on the next stroke, cancelling the effect.

Comment: @JCollins not a vacuum... need to understand the concept of lower than atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Copy that Solar Mike, we can agree that vacuum is just a word used to refer to pressures lower than atmosphere. Not sure how it adds to the discussion though.

Comment: @JCollins, it doesn't pull againt the next stroke because the intake valves are shut then.

Comment: If the throttle is closed completely, then is it not as good as having the inlet valves closed?

Comment: @JCollins sure, hard to do with a conventional valve train.  I guess you could shut the exhaust valves on the upstroke as well if you had the ability to open and shut valves at will, which is what a jake brake kind of does.

Answer (score 0):

You said it, the engine works as an air pump.

The engine is often tested on a dynamometer to establish the friction load ie turning with zero fuel.

Depending on the type of fuel and fuelling system, some engines will have zero fuel input on overrun, as some of the computer control is set to do this. On a slightly older carburetor system then fuel will still be drawn in.

So, max braking will be with the throttle closed with no fuel input, but as to how much braking will be down to the engine design as well including things like valve overlap etc.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, I'm suggesting that maximum braking is when the throttle is *partly* closed, that full closure may actually cause less engine braking.

Comment: @JCollins then you have to remember that the throttle is not a valve where the flow is fully shut off, it always allows air to pass - it is more a restriction than a valve as the idling engine still needs air + fuel.

Comment: I'm not sure you read this part of the question "if the throttle were completely shut and any idle valves, recirc valves etc. would be closed". Also an engine on overrun does not need fuel nor does it need to idle at that moment in time.

Comment: @JCollins yes I did, but you don't seem to understand that the throttle is **never** completely shut... And overrun fueling does depend on the type of fueling system.

Comment: Luckily my hypothetical engine can completely shut the throttle. Now in that hypothetical, what might we expect of engine braking?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking correctly, but it's not quite a as simple as it sounds.

You want to brake on the compressions and exhaust strokes with pressure, you don't want to brake with suction - that works the rings the wrong way and can cause oil to be sucked into the cylinders. So yes, you need air in there, and some spark delay and valve delay and fuel disable if you can manage it. Most modern gas engine don't do this much for emissions control reasons. VGTurbos can be used to help with exhaust back pressure, but they can only do so much.

Comment: Sorry Phil, I don't think anyone has understood the question, you probably got it better than most. On your point that you don't want a vacuum, while oil vacuum is going to be a problem, an idling engine makes vacuum anyways so is unlikely to be much different. For engine braking, the BMEP needs to be negative I understand. The thought was whether if the throttle was completely shut (or for that matter, we just eliminate the inlet camshaft and leave the valves sprung shut), that there would actually be a reduction in engine braking.